# event.preventDefault doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm currently working on a bot, nothing too fancy. Just some basic bot and the thing is that whenever I type google for example it refreshes the page even though I put two `event.preventDefault()`. And when somehow I fix this it opens two tabs (when google is typed) so I'm really confused about the problem.

JavaScript:

```
var INPUT = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
INPUT.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.forms[0].submit();
  }
});

function requester(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var valeur = (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value).toString().trim().toLowerCase();
  switch (valeur) {
    case "date": date(); break;
    case "day": day(); break;
    case "hour": hour(); break;
    case "stop": stopTime(); break;
    case "youtube": open("https://www.youtube.ca"); break;
    case "google": open("https://www.google.ca"); break;
    case "chrono": chrono(); break;
    case "refresh": location.reload(); break;
    case "my_playlist": open("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjhkALRcmTGR2MQ-Y5cMERhq15ieGOqBR"); break;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="requester(event)">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="font-size:150px;text-transform: uppercase;" autofocus>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.forms[0].submit()` doesn't fire a `submit` event:

> When invoking this method directly, no `submit` event is raised (in particular, the form's `onsubmit` event handler is not run),  and constraint validation is not triggered either.

(from [the MDN documentation for `HTMLFormElement.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit))

Additionally, default form submission is triggered by `keydown`, not `keyup`.

Two easy solutions:

1. Remove the `keyup` handler. Pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> in a form field will fire a `submit` event by default; you don't need to implement anything additional.
2. Alternatively, if you really want to have a keyboard handler, bind the handler to `keydown`, and call `requester` directly instead of calling `.submit()`.

Comment: Ok so I tried the second solution and it work, but as I said in my post when google is typed it opens two tabs, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Oh, duh. The other problem is that you're binding to `keyup`. This event is usually not used for anything -- keys trigger when pressed, not when released! You probably want `keydown` instead.